# Pathing commands on Windows 10

Tags: npm, webpack, node-modules, webpack-dev-server

This is one of the problems where I don't even know how to properly frame the question.

I'm trying to follow a React course on Lynda.com

The instructor says to type into my command window the following:

> node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server

But when I enter it I get

> 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

The autocomplete will fill in "node_modules" but not ".bin".  I've checked that webpack-dev-server.cmd is inside the .bin folder, and that npm is in my proper path. (yarn and npm both work as commands in this folder.)

I've tried several different command shells including ConEmu, but all throw the same error.

I'm really at a loss for how to proceed from here.  Is the problem that the instructor is using a different operating system and I'm just missing a subtle difference in the way that I have to enter the command?

Comment: I assume you're running on Linux? Windows won't recognize those forward slashes.

Comment: No, Windows 10 on my home computer.  I suspect the instructor is running on Linux, though.

Comment: Try using backslashes instead.

Comment: Ha!  the slashes ARE in the wrong direction!

Now it blows up on me, but at least it's recognizing the command.